# How do I find and replace all occurrences of a mapping of multiple replacements in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, find-replace

Is there a way of taking the native function of changing all occurrences within a file *at the same time*? Let's say change all FR1 to FR2 by selecting FR1 and pressing Ctrl+ F2 then typing FR2 and automate it for a list of 1 to 1 terms substitution. For example Selecting 3 or 10 different terms and replacing them for the assigned replacement. In comparison to for example running the replace all occurrences for each substitution and typing them individually.

maybe an extension that expands this native feature

I have only tried manually using Ctrl + F2 and type replacements for each of the different terms individually

e.g.

find one
Ctrl+F2
type uno
,
find two
Ctrl+F2
type dos
,
find n
Ctrl+F2
type x
...

Answer (score -1):

While using find and replace functionality you can simply use regular expressions to achive more complex behaviour of the replace mechanism -> [example](https://dev.to/rfornal/vs-code-search-and-replace-regex-mn2).

I think this is what you meant...

Comment: I don't think this will work for general cases of what is being asked for here.

Comment: Please give me a clear example.